# Eclipse - Change order of autocomplete suggestions

Tags: java, eclipse

I see that this has been asked before but I can't seem to find what I want. Currently, in Window>Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist, my Sort Proposals are set to "by relevance". However, they still seem to be sorting alphabetically. For example, whenever I have a `HashMap` and I start typing `map.put`, all of the `map.compute` suggestions come up first and I need to scroll all the way down to `map.put`. Is there a way to prevent this in Eclipse?

Comment: In Preference->Java->Content Assist, uncheck "Show substring matches".

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug of Eclipse Mylyn that has already been fixed:

[Eclipse Mylyn Bug 506804 - content assist substring matches should be sorted after prefix matches](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506804)

As workaround, in *Window > **Preferences: Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced*** in the upper area **uncheck *Java Proposals (Task-Focused)*** and **check *Java Proposals*** instead.

Alternatively, you can wait for the upcoming Eclipse 2020-09 release where this bug is fixed (or already [download the milestone 3 of this upcoming release here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2020-09/m3)).