# can i make eclipse select suggestion based on best match instead alphabetic order?

Tags: eclipse

what annoys me most about eclipse is, that it automatically selects the suggestions that comes first in alphabetic order, even if there is a suggestion that matches exactly what i typed. Like when i type `String.valueOf` the top suggestion(which is also the one selected) is `copyValueOf` and when just continue typing a '(', it automatically replaces my text with the suggestion. Can i somehow make eclipse to mark the best match instead of the alphabetically first?

Comment: Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63740032/6505250

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

This is a known bug of Eclipse Mylyn that is already fixed in Eclipse 2020-09:

[Eclipse Mylyn Bug 506804 - content assist substring matches should be sorted after prefix matches](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=506804)

**Solution:**

Make sure that your Eclipse is up-to-date: ***Help > Check for Updates***